# How to delete 1 row from the first 2 classes of a 3 classes dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with 3 classes (1, 2, 3). Each class has 4 samples. But I want that classes 1 and 2 have only 3 classes.
So I need to remove 1 row from each. It can be any one.

With my attempt, I can only remove the first row of the first class. 
How can I improve this?

```
#The dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(12,5))
label=np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3])

df['label'] = label


# My attempt
df1=df.drop(id==1)
df1
```

**EDIT**
Or It can be to sample 3 rows form classes 1 and 2; and 4 samples from class3.
In that case my code attempt:

```
df1 = pd.concat(g.sample(3) for idx, g in df.groupby('label'))
```

But...it samples 3 rows from all the classes!

ORIGINAL DATAFRAME

[image]

WHAT I NEED

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better and simplier solution is filtering in `list comprehension` with `if ... else` statement:

```
df1 = pd.concat(g.sample(3) if g.label.isin([1,2]).all() else g 
                for idx, g in df.groupby('label') )
print (df1)
           0         1         2         3         4  label
3   0.978624  0.811683  0.171941  0.816225  0.274074      1
1   0.121569  0.670749  0.825853  0.136707  0.575093      1
0   0.543405  0.278369  0.424518  0.844776  0.004719      1
4   0.431704  0.940030  0.817649  0.336112  0.175410      2
7   0.890412  0.980921  0.059942  0.890546  0.576901      2
5   0.372832  0.005689  0.252426  0.795663  0.015255      2
8   0.742480  0.630184  0.581842  0.020439  0.210027      3
9   0.544685  0.769115  0.250695  0.285896  0.852395      3
10  0.975006  0.884853  0.359508  0.598859  0.354796      3
11  0.340190  0.178081  0.237694  0.044862  0.505431      3
```

---

Another solution is create mask by `groupby` and [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with filtered `DataFrame` with `isin` and added `True` values by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html).

Last use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(12,5))
label=np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3])

df['label'] = label
#print (df)
```

```
N = 3
vals = [1,2]
s = df.loc[df.label.isin(vals), 'label']
mask = s.groupby(s).cumcount() < N
mask = mask.reindex(df.index, fill_value=True)
print (mask)
0      True
1      True
2      True
3     False
4      True
5      True
6      True
7     False
8      True
9      True
10     True
11     True
dtype: bool

print (df[mask])
           0         1         2         3         4  label
0   0.543405  0.278369  0.424518  0.844776  0.004719      1
1   0.121569  0.670749  0.825853  0.136707  0.575093      1
2   0.891322  0.209202  0.185328  0.108377  0.219697      1
4   0.431704  0.940030  0.817649  0.336112  0.175410      2
5   0.372832  0.005689  0.252426  0.795663  0.015255      2
6   0.598843  0.603805  0.105148  0.381943  0.036476      2
8   0.742480  0.630184  0.581842  0.020439  0.210027      3
9   0.544685  0.769115  0.250695  0.285896  0.852395      3
10  0.975006  0.884853  0.359508  0.598859  0.354796      3
11  0.340190  0.178081  0.237694  0.044862  0.505431      3
```

Better explanation of `mask`:

```
#select values of label where need remove some rows to count = N
s = df.loc[df.label.isin(vals), 'label']
print (s)
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    2
Name: label, dtype: int32
```

```
#groupby in filtered df, so length of df is different as original
mask = s.groupby(s).cumcount() < N
print (mask)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
dtype: bool

#added missing rows be reindex - NaN are replaced by True
mask = mask.reindex(df.index, fill_value=True)
print (mask)
0      True
1      True
2      True
3     False
4      True
5      True
6      True
7     False
8      True
9      True
10     True
11     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: What does  < N mean?

Comment: It is less as constant `3`, I change it.

Comment: Can you give me more explanation, please?

Comment: So if need only `2` rows for `labels=1,3` you can change constant `N=2` and `vals = [1,3]`. I try more general solution...

Comment: Sure, give me a sec.

Answer (score 0):

also you can use ranking rows by groups and than filtering:

```
df['rank']= df.groupby('label')[0].rank(ascending=False)
df.loc[(df['rank']<=3),:]
```

Comment: I get 3 samples for each class. I need 3 for classes 1 and 2; and 4 for class 3.